# i have this type of array i want to print this array how to print in php

Tags: php

`print_r($checksLists);`

for about output is this

```
Array
(
[states] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [status] => up
                [timefrom] => 1516849684
                [timeto] => 1517396400
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [status] => down
                [timefrom] => 1516849564
                [timeto] => 1516849684
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [status] => up
                [timefrom] => 1515446404
                [timeto] => 1516849564
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [status] => unknown
                [timefrom] => 1515446224
                [timeto] => 1515446404
            )

        [4] => Array
            (
                [status] => up
                [timefrom] => 1512566104
                [timeto] => 1515446224
            )

        [5] => Array
            (
                [status] => down
                [timefrom] => 1512563104
                [timeto] => 1512566104
            )

        [6] => Array
            (
                [status] => up
                [timefrom] => 1512126000
                [timeto] => 1512563104
            )

    )

)
```

1st problem

how to print the status value

I am trying like this 
      `echo $checksLists.states[1].status;`

but I am not getting output

2nd problem
from this, I want to print the new array with only up status values like this

```
    [0] => Array
        (
            [status] => up
            [timefrom] => 1515446404
            [timeto] => 1516849564
        )



    [1] => Array
        (
            [status] => up
            [timefrom] => 1512566104
            [timeto] => 1515446224
        )



    [2] => Array
        (
            [status] => up
            [timefrom] => 1512126000
            [timeto] => 1512563104
        )
```

Comment: It's an array not an object so use this format $checksLists['states'][0]'status']

Answer (score 1):

**For you 1st problem**, maybe you are confused between javascript and php object access notation. To access `objects` in **PHP** the proper notation is `->` (arrow sign) and for array `[]` (bracket sign). As it is just a multidimensional php array. So treat it like `array`  using `[]` sign this way.

You just mixed up the javascript version object access using `.`. For php dot (`.`) sign is usually used for concatenation purpose.

```
echo $checksLists['states'][1]['status'];
```

**For you 2nd problem**, you can try like this to filter out your array where value is `up` using [array_filter()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php)

```
$filtered_array = array_filter($checksLists['states'], function ($var) {
    return ($var['status'] == 'up');
});

print '<pre>';
print_r($filtered_array);
print '</pre>';
```

Comment: First time to know that you can access objects in PHP like tho `echo $checksLists.states[1].status;`, I guess it's better to notify about the totally wrong syntax too.

Comment: @hassan sorry. where you get that `echo $checksLists.states[1].status;` on my answer? Am I made any mistake while typing ? please let me know

Comment: "For you 1st problem, it is not an object" while the OP posted that syntax, a beginner may get that it's okay to handle objects like this

Comment: @hassan Yes you're ri8, my wording was not ri8 for a beginner. Please have a look on my edit and let me know may I need to be more verbose/correct anything else

Comment: Notice:  Undefined index: status in C:\xampp\htdocs\pingdom\pingdom\report.php on line 100

Array
(
)
hi

Comment: @chandana put `$checksLists['states']` as the first parameter of `array_filter()`. See my edit and let me know whether it is still showing undefined notice?

Answer (score 0):

First part of your problem is you need the correct syntax to access mutli-dimentional arrays:

```
$checksLists['states'][0]['status']
```

Armed with that, you can loop over the `$checklists['states']` array and print out matches:

```
$newArray = [];

foreach($checklists['states'] as $id=>$attr) {
    if ($attr['status'] == 'up') {
        $newArray[] = $attr;
    }
}

print_r($newArray);
```

Once you understand how that works, check out `array_filter()` for a shorter/faster way to do this.